# how to echo row table with rowspan in a specific condition inside while loop of query result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

i have this kind of report

[image]

i want to make a report like in the image above.
i already try it with this code :

```
$id = 0;
    $id2 = 0;
    $no = 1;
    $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pendidikan, unsur, subunsur WHERE pendidikan.id_sub = subunsur.id_sub AND subunsur.id_unsur = unsur.id_unsur AND pendidikan.nidn = $_GET[nidn]");
    $q4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pendidikan, unsur, subunsur WHERE pendidikan.id_sub = subunsur.id_sub AND subunsur.id_unsur = unsur.id_unsur AND pendidikan.nidn = $_GET[nidn]");
    $data = array();
        while($d=mysql_fetch_assoc($q3)){
            $no++;
            if($id != $d['id_unsur']){
                $no = $no+1;
                echo"<tr>
                        <td>$d[kode_unsur]</td>
                        <td colspan='8'>$d[nama_unsur]</td>
                    </tr>";
                while($f=mysql_fetch_array($q3)){
                    if($id2 != $f['id_sub']){
                    echo"<tr>
                        <td rowspan='$no'>$d[kode_sub]</td>
                        <td colspan='8'>$d[nama_sub]</td>
                    </tr>";
                    }
                    $id2 = $f['id_sub'];
                    while($g=mysql_fetch_assoc($q4)){
                        if($g['id_sub'] == $f['id_sub']){
                            echo"<tr>
                                    <td>$g[no_butir]</td>
                                    <td>$g[uraian]</td>
                                    <td>$g[thn_smt_akademik]</td>
                                    <td>$g[tanggal]</td>
                                    <td>$g[satuan_hasil]</td>
                                    <td>$g[jml_vlm_kegiatan]</td>
                                    <td>$g[jml_angka_kredit]</td>
                                    <td>$g[bukti]</td>
                                </td>";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            $id = $d['id_unsur'];
        }
```

what should i do, because with that code, im creating row with the same sub A, not B like this :

[image]

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, and using a deprecated/removed driver. Also why are you executing the same query 3 times and defining it twice?

Comment: @user3783243 because im so confused, i dont know how to make it, any idea how to do that mate?

Comment: You need to stop using the obsolete `mysql_*` functions, they've been deprecated for years and removed in the current version of PHP. Convert to PDO or mysqli.